# Create a constructor, that is capabe take any number of arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

So the class B constructor should take any number of `A*` as arguments, and simply `push_back` these pointers to `_vec` vector.

I tried to use variadic templates, `std::initalizer_list`. Nothing seems to fit. Maybe I over complicate the problem here. Could not find a solution anywhere in the last 2 days.

```
//very shematic code, just to get the idea
Class A
{
    //members
};
Class B
{
private:
    std::vector<A*> _vec; 
public:
    B(A* much_arguments) 
    {
    _vec.push_back(much_arguments); //schematically
    //do other stuff;
    }
};
```

Comment: Show us what you did past two days. I was expecting the question with such title not to mention the techniques for the solution. What were your attempts and what was wrong?

Comment: Why not just have `B` take a `std::vector<A*>`?  Then the code becomes `B(std::vector<A*> vec) : _vec(std::move(vec)) { other stuff }`

Comment: `std::initializer_list<A*>` should work as intended, what problem did you encounter with it?

Comment: B(std::initalizer_list<A*> list) {//something;}
in main:
B bstuff(&A,&A,&A);
no matching function for call B::B(A*,A*,A*)

Comment: You could write a variadic template.

Comment: @JesperJuhl
I couldnt figure out a way without calling it recursively, which creates a separate object on every call.

Comment: @Benjámin `&A,&A,&A` is three separate arguments. An `initializer_list` is enclosed in curly braces, like `{&A, &A, &A}`.

Comment: See this link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack especially the section about "Pack expansion".

Comment: @NathanOliver
Well that would work, but it feels a bit clunky. I might as well just write a few type of the constructor.

Comment: @molbdnilo
Now this one worked. Thanks :)
JesperJuhl:
I read this before, but to be honest, I still dont know whats going on there, and how to reach parameter_pack arguments separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be using `std::initializer_list`:

```
//very shematic code, just to get the idea
class A
{
    //members
};
class B
{
private:
    std::vector<A*> _vec;

public:    
    B(std::initializer_list<A*> many_arguments):
            _vec {many_arguments}
    {
    //do other stuff;
    }
};
```

[See it online!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FpJEiuqfKGHeaq2R)

---

**EDIT** after information in comments:
`std::initializer_list` is not a magical wand. It won't let you do `B::B(A*, A*, A*)`. Instead, you have to use it in one of the following ways:

```
B myObject {new A(), new A(), new A()}; //uniform initialization
B myOtherObject({new A(), new A(), new A()}); // explicit initialization with single std::initializer_list
```

---

Side note: Dealing with raw pointers is rarely a good idea. Prefer `std::unique_ptr<A>` or `std::shared_ptr<A>` over raw pointer `A*`.

Comment: It is you who use `new`. `A a1; A a2; A a3; B b{&a1, &a2, &a3}` would be fine.